# Android Studio Faild to complete Gradle execution 5

Tags: java, android, android-studio, antivirus, virus

Hello there i faced a problem with android studio while building project, suddenly my antivirus says that "Ransomware detected" on my device  in

> jre\bin\java.exe

as you see in the below screenshot

[image]

however java is up-to date 9.0.4  , also android studio 3.0.1

any idea about what happened

Note that this is the second time that happens

Comment: How about removing that Anti-virus...?

Comment: i didn't get what are you mean  !

Comment: Remove that anti-virus' process. I mean.. just kill it! You can kill it with this shortcut, Ctrl + Shift + Esc (Task Manager) → Process Tab -> Find Anti-Virus' name → kill it